# Similarities and Differences between Cylinder Equations

Tags: 3d, cylindrical-coordinates

Describe the intersection of x^2 + y^2 ≤ 1 and y^2 + z^2 ≤ 1 and x^2 + z^2 ≤ 1.

How is this intersection the same as x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ 1? How is it different?

When I graphed them in GeoGebra, they all laid right on top of one another as if they had all points in common. How are they the same and different? [image]

Comment: When you ask GeoGebra to plot `x^2+y^2<=1` you don’t get a cylinder. You get a disk. You’re not going to be able to tell anything useful about the problem from these plots.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2+y^2 + z^2 \le 1 \implies x^2+y^2 \le 1$. Similarly for the other inequalities.

However, consider points like $(\sqrt{0.5}, \sqrt{0.5}, \sqrt{0.5})$, it is inside the intersection of the cylinders but it is not inside the unit sphere.

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 equations are cylinders, it is the intersection of 3 perpendicular cylinders of radius 1 with their axis on the x,y and z axis. $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1$ describes a sphere of radius 1.